# Filter array without overriding

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to filter this array on changing the input "filter" but when i try to type it filters well but override the original list. So how can I filter the list on typing and returns to the original list on erasing the filter value?

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
        { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
        { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
        { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
        { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
    ])

const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')

const handleFilter = e => {
    setFilter(e.target.value)
    const personsFiltered = persons.filter(({ name }) => name.includes(filter))
    if (personsFiltered.length > 0)
        setPersons(personsFiltered)
}

return (
    <div>
        <input value={filter} onChange={handleFilter} />
        {persons.map((person, index) => <p key={index}>{person.name} {person.number}</p>)}
    </div>
)
```

Comment: Where is your render code for the persons? You could more easily do this by performing a filter on the render function rather than mutating the list

Comment: Do not store filtered array in state it can be computed from what you already have in state. If you find filtering on demand is a performance bottleneck use `useMemo` to memoize the result.

Comment: You need to have a copy of original to perform filter on. when you need it just reset it with the original one.

Comment: Thanks for updating your code - please see my answer for how to achieve this as part of the code you are already rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you want by filtering your results as part of the render. You are updating your `filter` state so the re-render should trigger as expected on event:

**EDIT:** I see that you updated your question with your rendering code. You should be able to just apply the `filter` function to what you already have:

```js
{persons.filter(({ name }) => name.includes(filter)).map((person, index) => <p key={index}>{person.name} {person.number}</p>)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to maintain the additional state for the filtered values.

Just use another `useState`

```
const [persons, setPersons] = useState([
  { name: 'Arto Hellas', number: '040-123456' },
  { name: 'Ada Lovelace', number: '39-44-5323523' },
  { name: 'Dan Abramov', number: '12-43-234345' },
  { name: 'Mary Poppendieck', number: '39-23-6423122' }
])

// use additional state here
const [personsFiltered, setPersonsFiltered] = useState(persons);

const [filter, setFilter] = useState('')

const handleFilter = e => {
setFilter(e.target.value)
const personsFiltered = persons.filter(({ name }) => name.includes(filter))
if (personsFiltered.length > 0)
  // set the additional state here
  setPersonsFiltered(personsFiltered)
}

return(<input value={filter} onChange={handleFilter} />)
```

Comment: Using another state for this is unnecessary in my opinion - it just leaves another state to manage and be aware of when we can perform filtering logic as part of the rendering.

Comment: you still have to have the original list somewhere, and each input change should check against the original list, not the already filtered list. normally that original list would come from props, instead of defining it inside the component

Comment: You can perform the filter as part of the render and not have to worry about any of these problems, though.

Comment: That's true in some cases. It all depends on if you're doing other things with the filtered array before rendering the component.